# c# - conditional operator expression (a few in a row)

Tags: c#, logic, conditional-operator

```
bool isGeneric = variableA != null ? variableB != null ? false : true : true;
```

I came across this line. Can anyone decipher this line/group them into parenthesis for me?

Comment: I just want to throw out that code like that is terrible if for no other reason than it's hard to read.  It would be much better to group it with paranthesis, or even better to write something like this out with if statements.  For example `isGeneric = variableA != null ? (variableB != null ? false : true) : true;`

Comment: haha... meh.. i thought so.. i met this code at my work place.. will definitely change it to that! Thanks bro :D

Comment: Yeah, I figured. I've seen some truly terrifying things in my job's code base too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a ternary inside of a ternary:

```
bool isGeneric = variableA != null 
    ? (variableB != null ? false : true) 
    : (true);
```

If `variableA` is not equal to null, check the first condition, else return true.  In the first condition, return `false` if `variableB` is not null and return `true` if it is.

You could also translate it into the following if/else statements:

```
bool isGeneric = false;
if (variableA != null) 
{
    if (variableB != null)
        isGeneric = false;
    else 
        isGeneric = true;
}
else
    isGeneric = true;
```

Comment: Where is my gun I want to kill someone.
that should be 

   " bool isGeneric = (variableA == null || variableB == null) "

Comment: @ahsant naturally, but that's not an accurate explanation of the code as written :).